# 4 queens algorithm - can't understand code

Tags: java

```
public boolean canPlaceQueen(int r, int c) {
    /**
     * Returns TRUE if a queen can be placed in row r and column c.
     * Otherwise it returns FALSE. x[] is a global array whose first (r-1)
     * values have been set.
     */
    // System.out.println("r======"+r);
    // System.out.println("c="+c);
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        System.out.println("iiiiiiiiiii="+i);
        if (x[i] == c || (i - r) == (x[i] - c) ||(i - r) == (c - x[i]))
        {
             System.out.println("try c="+c);
             System.out.println("try="+r);
            return false;

        }
    }
    return true;

}

public void placeNqueens(int r, int n) {
    /**
     * Using backtracking this method prints all possible placements of n
     * queens on an n x n chessboard so that they are non-attacking.
     */
    //System.out.println("r="+r);
    for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
        //System.out.println("c=="+c);
        if (canPlaceQueen(r, c)) {
            x[r] = c;
           // System.out.println("2nd==="+r);
            if (r == n - 1) {
                printQueens(x);
            } else {
                placeNqueens(r + 1, n);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: If c = 0, then c = 1, but then c=0. I cant understand that logic, why not c=2,please describe it or describe how c increment in this program

Comment: Which lines are you referring to?

Comment: "If c = 0, then c = 1, but then c=0." – WAT. Like, what are you even talking about?

Comment: i mean the incremental fact of c

Comment: for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
        //System.out.println("c=="+c);
        if (canPlaceQueen(r, c)) {
            x[r] = c;
           // System.out.println("2nd==="+r);
            if (r == n - 1) {
                printQueens(x);
            } else {
                placeNqueens(r + 1, n);

Comment: Do you not understand the syntax of a `for` loop?  Is that what's confusing you?

Comment: i am confused with recursive

Comment: The reason the value of c goes 0, 1, 0 is because you are recursively calling placeQueens inside your loop. The second 0 is inside a new instance of placeQueens execution that has started from scratch after being called from within the first execution. This c variable has a different scope than the c variable that was c=0 and c=1.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'll take a crack at this.  You enter the method placeNqueens with r=0 and n=whatever (let's say 5). We loop through each column and check if we can fit a queen in that column for row . If we CAN place it, we set the x[0] = c (which will probably be 0 for the first attempt) and then recursively call into placeNqueens with r=1 and n=5. At this point we're checking the next row.

Inside this call, we now start again and check all the columns. We won't be able to place it in the first column, because that's where the first queen is, so we loop until we find a column we can place it. Inside this loop, you might check column 0 and fail, and then check column 1 and fail, and then check column 2 and find a spot, so you set x[1] = 2 and then call placeNqueens(6, 5).

Eventually you've placed enough queens that your row == queens -1, so then you print the solution. If you don't ever find a solution, then the call stack ends and falls back to the previous call, which keeps looping until it finds ANOTHER possible place to put the queen in that row. When it does, it then calls placeNqueens to try the next row again. If a solution is present, eventually the algorithm will try all the permutations needed to find it.

So, to summarize, in each execution of placeNqueens, you loop only as long as you need to loop until you find a spot to place your queen, and then you call placeNqueens again, reducing your current row position by 1. If you reach a point where you cannot place any queens, your program will finish the entire for-loop and then return, which takes you to wherever you left off in the loop on the previous call.